# how to show breaks, newlines between the words as we write in database?

Tags: php, sql

[image]

I feed those info with spaces and new lines but when i fetch these info it shows in only single word gap

my code is:

```
<?php include_once("template_header.php");?>
<div id="pageContent">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="20%" valign="top"><img src="inventory_images/<?php echo $id; ?>.jpg"width="200"height="188" alt="<?php echo $product_name; ?>"/><br/>
    <a href="inventory_images/<?php echo $id; ?>.jpg">View Full Size Image</a></td>
    <td width="80%" valign="top"><h3><?php echo $product_name; ?></h3>
    <p><?php echo "Rs. ".$price; ?><p>ADD TO CART<br/>
    <br/>
    <?php echo "$subcategory  $category";?><br/>
    <br/>
    <?php echo '</br>' ,($details); ?>
    <br/>
    </p>
</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What variable is missing the new lines? I'd guess you need `nl2br`.